# Implementing Delay with Task

Tags: c#, task

Due to twitter rating limitation of 180 request per 15 minute. I made this implementation and delay to the task. But it doesn't seems to work. Whats an issue with this?

What i implemented is actually am giving a 15 minutes wait after 180 request. Whether my implementation correct?

```
var currentRequestIndex = 1;
var timeToDelay = 0;
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var contactFeed = item;
    if(currentRequestIndex % 180 == 0)
    {
        timeToDelay = currentRequestIndex*5000;
    }

    Delay(timeToDelay * 5000).ContinueWith(_ => Task.Factory.StartNew(
                                                () =>
                                                -- call to twitter api here 
                                          ));
    currentRequestIndex++;
}

public Task Delay(int milliseconds)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    new Timer(_ => tcs.SetResult(null)).Change(milliseconds, -1);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you set `timeToDelay` to 0 and then wait `timeToDelay * 5000` which given the former is also 0.

**Solution 1 - Spread them evenly**

Let's assume your network has no lag and all requests are send to twitter immediately. Then in order to spread your requests evenly during the 15 minutes interval you should delay the `i`th request by precisely `i * 15 * 6000 / 180`

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var contactFeed = item;

    delayTime = currentRequestIndex * 15 * 6000 / 180;
    Delay(timeToDelay).ContinueWith(_ => Task.Factory.StartNew(
                                                () =>
                                                -- call to twitter api here 
                                          ));
    currentRequestIndex++;
}
```

**Solution 2 - Send them all at once, wait for the rest of the 15 minutes to pass**

I'll just post the code, it's pretty much self-explanatory.

```
Action makeRequests = () =>
{
   DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
   foreach (var item in items)
   {
       // Call twitter api here
   }
   TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now - start;
   Delay(15 * 6000 - diff.Milliseconds).ContinueWith(_ => Task.StartNew(makeRequests));
};
makeRequests();
```

P. S. By the looks of it, are using .NET v4.0, but if I'm mistaken and you are compiling against v4.5 you can use the built-in `Task.Delay method`.

Comment: Thanks, What you did will add delay for every request right? What i really need at 1st 15 min 180 request can be made. then 2nd 15 min another 180 request can be made. I implemented in that way.

Comment: Check my edit. I thought you were trying to do what my 1st solution does. Anyway, both of the above will suffice, but solution 2 is better since it is using only a single `Task` per 180 requests.

Comment: +1 Hi thanks again. With solution 2 how will it make only 180 requests per 15 minute? Can you pls explain the code? i didn't see any check for 15 min and 180 requests.

Comment: Take the time you started sending the requests. Send all the requests. Calculate the elapsed time by subtracting the start time from the current. Now, in 15 minutes there are 15 * 6000 ms. If we subtract `15 * 6000 - diff` we'll get what the amount of the time we need to wait until 15 minutes have passed.     
I actually assumed that the number of items is precisely 180 in the loop. If that's not the case, send the first 180 requests, then break out of the foreach, wait until 15 minutes have passed and start from 181st item in the next loop.

Comment: Just a quick correction: 15 minutes would be 15 * 60000 - not 15 * 6000, which would be 90 seconds.